# Feedzirra incompatible with Rails 3.1.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedzirra

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "builder":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       rails (= 3.1.1) depends on
>         builder (~> 3.0.0)
>
> ```
> feedzirra (~> 0.1.1) depends on
>   builder (2.1.2)
> ```

Does it mean, that the latest feedzirra version is incompatible with the latest rails version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to archiloque](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra/issues/75), "It's already done in commit 26532da, I just need to release a new version the includes this change"

For now, putting this in your Gemfile should fix that issue:

gem 'feedzirra', :git => 'https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra.git'

The specific revision that worked for me is:
  remote: https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra.git
  revision: dee1454980e7b93022776cd047ad419da3999332